# How to toggle unleash feature flag through api for a specific environments

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my project, I have three environments and I want to toggle a feature flag only on for a  specific environment
Is it possible to toggle unleash feature flag with API for a development environment only? I am using the below code to toggle the flag  but it works for default mode only

function enabledToggle() {
axios
.get("http://unleash.host.com/api/admin/features/:featureName/toggle/on", {
headers: {
Authorization: `${"my-token"}`,
}
})
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
}

I also tried one more way but I got this error
I am trying to turn on the feature flag through this API but I am getting an error
when I execute the above function I am getting this error
Request failed with status code 415
can anyone help what I am doing wrong?
here is my code

function oNFeatureFlag(){

axios({url:"https://host.name/api/admin/projects/default/features/feature-name/environments/development/on",
headers: {`Authorization: ${"my token"}`,},
method: "post",
})
.then(function (response) {
console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});}

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `content-type` to `application/json` explicitly.

This is most likely because of the way Axios sets the `content-type` header. From what I understand, it sets `content-type` to `application/json;charset=utf-8`. Prior to a recent version of Unleash, Unleash didn't parse this properly, so it would give you a 415 Unsupported Media Type response.

For reference, [here's the same question as a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Unleash/unleash/issues/1367).